# Actuaizar un registro cuando se cumpla una condicion sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hola buenos dias quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que una vez el empleado cumpla años de antiguedad el periodo "proporcional" se actualize a 0, como pueden ver en la primera parte del codigo esta el periodo proporcional y este se va calculando en base a la antiguedad del empleado, pero lo que quiero es que una vez el empleado cumpla un año mas de antiguedad el periodo propocional regrese a 0 nuevamente.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[pGenerarVacaciones] 
AS 
BEGIN   
    -- Verificar si ya existe el periodo '0000'     
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MovimientoVacaciones WHERE ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL')   
    BEGIN       
        -- Actualizar el periodo '0000'         
        UPDATE mv       
        SET mv.VACACIONES_GENERADAS = CASE 
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años < 1 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24)
                    WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18)
                    ELSE 0          END,            
            mv.Inicio = GETDATE(),          
            mv.Fin = GETDATE(),             
            mv.Antiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, U.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        FROM dbo.MovimientoVacaciones mv        
        INNER JOIN dbo.Empleados U ON mv.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu         
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad](GETDATE()) Antiguedad ON U.Id_Usu = Antiguedad.Id_Usu         
        WHERE mv.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL'   
    END     
    ELSE    
    BEGIN
        -- Crear el periodo '0000'      
        INSERT INTO dbo.MovimientoVacaciones 
        SELECT U.Id_Usu, Anio = 'PROPORCIONAL',             Dias = CASE 
                WHEN Antiguedad.años < 1 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 36)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 1 AND Antiguedad.años < 2 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 30)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 2 AND Antiguedad.años < 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 24)
                WHEN Antiguedad.años >= 3 THEN (((Antiguedad.Meses * 30) + Antiguedad.dias) / 18)
                ELSE 0          END,            
                Inicio = GETDATE(),             
                Fin = GETDATE(),            
                0,          
                Antiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, U.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        FROM dbo.Empleados U        
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad](GETDATE()) Antiguedad ON U.Id_Usu = Antiguedad.Id_Usu         
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM MovimientoVacaciones mov 
                        WHERE mov.ID_EMPLEADO = U.Id_Usu 
                        AND mov.ANO = 'PROPORCIONAL')   
    END 
    ---UNA VEZ SE CREE EL NUEVO PERIODO DESEO ACTUALIZAR EL PERIODO "PROPORCIONAL" A 0  
    -- Crear los demás periodos

    INSERT INTO dbo.MovimientoVacaciones    
    SELECT Id_Usu, 
            Anio = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
            Dias, 
            GETDATE(), 
            GETDATE(), 
            0, 
            Antiguedad = DATEDIFF(YEAR, empleado.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)   
    FROM dbo.Empleados empleado     
    INNER JOIN DiasPorAño tabla ON DATEDIFF(YEAR, empleado.FechaIngreso, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN tabla.LimiteInferior AND tabla.LimiteSuperior   
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MovimientoVacaciones mov 
                    WHERE mov.ID_EMPLEADO = empleado.Id_Usu 
                    AND  YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = mov.ANO AND mov.ANO <> 'PROPORCIONAL') 
END
```